# $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof that $f(x) = x^3 /(x^2+y^2)$, $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$, is continuous at $(0,0)$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I need to prove that $f$  continuous at $(x, y)=(0,0)$ using a $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof
$$
  f(x, y) = \begin{cases}
\frac{x^3}{{x^2 + y^2}},&(x,y)\neq (0,0)
\\
0,&(x,y) = (0,0)
\end{cases}
$$

I'm not sure how to manipulate the function to get $\delta$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Use that $\displaystyle\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}\le 1$. Then start the proof like

> Assume we are given an $\varepsilon>0$. Let $\delta:=$ ...
>
> If the $(x,y)$ point is closer to $(0,0)$ than $\delta$, then, in particular, $|x|<\delta$, so ...

Comment: the numerator is $x^3$

Comment: Exactly. That is, $x\cdot x^2$.

Comment: oh ok ok my bad thanks!

Comment: $\delta:=\varepsilon$

Answer (score 3):

You can use polar coordinates to see the problem more clearly:
$$f(r,\theta)=\frac{r^3 \cos^3(\theta)}{r^2} = r \cos^3(\theta)$$
Thus, for any $\epsilon>0$, choose $\delta=\epsilon$. If $r<\delta$:
$$|f(r,\theta)-0| < |r \cos^3(\theta)-0|<|r|<\delta=\epsilon$$