# Show that $f$ is not totally differentiable at $x=(0,0)$ by proof by contradiction.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Show that $f$ is not totally differentiable at $x=(0,0)$ by proof by contradiction.
  f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
 \frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2},&(x,y)\neq (0,0)
\\
0,&(x,y) = (0,0)
\end{cases}

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309689/epsilon-delta-proof-that-fx-x3-x2y2-x-y-ne-0-0-is-co?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, to proof that function of two variables doesn't have limit at some point, or it's not differentiable at point the following technique is used.

To the function of two variables $f(x,y)$ to have limit at some target point $A(x,y)$ it's necessary that for any arbitrary path that leads to $A$ the limit exists and all of them don't depend on that path and have same value.

To prove opposite, sometimes ray-type paths are used. For the point $A(0,0)$ rays are $y=kx$ family.

In practice, to the function
$$
f(x) = \left \{ 
\begin{array}{lc}
\frac {x^3}{x^2+y^2} & (x,y) = (0,0) \\
0 & (x,y) \ne (0,0)
\end{array}
\right .
$$
to be differentiable at $(0,0)$ the following limit has to exist
$$
\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac {\frac {x^3}{x^2+y^2}}{\Delta_{xy}} = \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac {x^3}{\left (x^2+y^2 \right)\Delta_{xy}}
$$
where $\Delta_{xy}$ is a infinitesimal increment along the path. Now let's chose paths along the rays $y = kx$, so $\Delta_{xy} = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$
$$
\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac {x^3}{\left (x^2+y^2 \right)^{\frac 32}} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0 }\frac {x^3}{\left (x^2+k^2x^2 \right)^{\frac 32}} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0 } \frac 1{\left (k^2+1 \right)^{\frac 32}} = \left (\frac 1{k^2+1}\right)^{\frac 32}
$$
So that limit actually depends on $k$, hence on the path that we chose to approach $(0,0)$, and thereof is not differentiable at that point.

Comment: In the limit as $(x,y)$ tends to $(0,0)$, shouldn't the denominator rather be $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$? Or are you taking the $y=0$ direction?

Comment: @Berci I don't see what it should be $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, the function itself has $x^2+y^2$

Comment: @Berci oh my, I was looking for other denominator. Thanks for pointing it out. I'll fix it in a sec.

Answer (score 3):

One can easily find the partial derivatives at the origin: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=1,\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=0$, so that the gradient there is $\nabla f(0,0)=(1,0)$. The directional derivative of $f$ at the origin, in the direction of $\hat{v}=(\cos \theta,\sin \theta)$ is $D_\hat{v}f(0,0)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f((0,0)+h \hat{v})-f(0,0)}{h}=\cos^3 \theta$.

*Suppose* now that $f$ is totally differentiable at the origin. In that case the directional derivative $D_\hat{v} f(0,0)$ is equal to the dot product $\nabla f(0,0) \cdot \hat{v}$. This is clearly false (at least for some unit vectors $\hat{v}$)

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following three functions:

$$g_1(x) = f(x,0)$$
$$g_2(x) = f(0,x)$$
$$g_3(x) = f(x,x)$$

If $f$ is totally differentiable at $0$, there is a relationship that must hold between the derivative of $g_1$, $g_2$ and $g_3$ at 0. What is that relationship? Then, show that it does not hold.